# Asp.net webforms update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I've a webform. On a dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event I run the given code to populate the form with details.

```
protected void ddlRequest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Requests where RequestID = '" + ddlRequest.SelectedItem.Value + "'", conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataSet dsrequest = new DataSet();

                    try
                    {

                        Adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        Adpt.Fill(dsrequest);
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            string RequesterID = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RequesterID"].ToString();
                            string OrgID = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OrgID"].ToString();
                            string CaseID = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CaseID"].ToString();
                            string PatientFName = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientFName"].ToString();
                            string PatientLName = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientLName"].ToString();
                            string PatientAge = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientAge"].ToString();
                            string PatientGender = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientGender"].ToString();
                            string MedicalCondition = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MedicalCondition"].ToString();
                            string PatientMoNo = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientMoNo"].ToString();
                            string Remark = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Remark"].ToString();
                            string RequestStatus = dsrequest.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RequestStatus"].ToString();



                            ddlRequesterID.SelectedValue = RequesterID;
                            ddlOrgID.SelectedValue = OrgID;
                            txtCaseID.Text = CaseID;
                            txtPatientFName.Text = PatientFName;
                            txtPatientLName.Text = PatientLName;
                            txtPatientAge.Text = PatientAge;
                            txtPatientGender.Text = PatientGender;
                            txtMedicalCondition.Text = MedicalCondition;
                            txtPatientMoNo.Text = PatientMoNo;
                            txtRemark.Text = Remark;
                            ddlRequestStatus.SelectedValue = RequestStatus;

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Once user updates required fields on submit button click event I want to update the record with the values in various input fields.

with code given below.

```
protected void btnSubmitReq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ddlRequest.SelectedValue == "0")
                {
                    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsRequests", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequesterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlRequesterID.SelectedValue;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrgID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgID.SelectedValue;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CaseID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCaseID.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientFName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientFName.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientLName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientLName.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientAge", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientAge.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientGender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientGender.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MedicalCondition", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMedicalCondition.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientMoNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientMoNo.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remark", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRemark.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlRequestStatus.SelectedValue;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOwner", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dbTstamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdRequests", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequesterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRequesterID.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrgID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrgID.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CaseID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCaseID.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientFName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientFName.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientLName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientLName.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientAge", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientAge.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientGender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientGender.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MedicalCondition", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMedicalCondition.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientMoNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPatientMoNo.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remark", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRemark.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlRequestStatus.SelectedValue;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dbTstamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Original_RequestID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRequest.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRequest.SelectedValue);

                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This doesn't update the record.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I was putting EnableViewState="false" in ddlRequest which was causing this issue. I removed it. Now everything working fine.

Thanks.